# Wit AI got 500 (internal server error) while using python API

Tags: python, facebook, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, wit-ai

I got 500 (internal server error) while using Wit AI python API. Is there a way to resolve this issue? My program was running fine yesterday and I did not change any line of the code. Or is it simply the server side error?

The problem screen shot
[image]

Much appreciate for any response!

Comment: If you are sure you haven't changed anything it is most likely server side issue only. Try reaching out to wit.ai forums or help.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Problem resolved! I have they have fixed it.